# Is there a way to calculate $x^{\frac{a}{b}}$ without using roots?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Is there a universal algorhitm to calculate $x^{\frac{a}{b}}$ without calculating b-root from $x^a$ ? Simply put, I'd just like to get a grasp on how the official way using roots was derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that for $x>0$:

$$x^{\frac ab}=e^{\frac ab\ln(x)}.$$